# Decoding byte array into String format error. [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, json, format, decoding

My application loads Tweets to an Oracle NoSQL database, then I retrieve them, and parse the JSON with Jackson library to obtain the values I need.

I have 2 problems in my code, though I'm pretty sure one comes from the other. The first problem comes from decoding the byte array (byte []) I get from my database into a String.

This is how the Tweet, which is a JSON String, is encoded and saved into the database:

```
Value myValue = Value.createValue(Base64.getEncoder().encode(msg.value().getBytes()));
```

This saves into the DB the tweet as a [Value object](https://docs.oracle.com/database/nosql-12.2.4.4/javadoc/oracle/kv/Value.html#createValue-byte:A-) from a byte array.

Now, I need to retrieve this Value object, and get the byte Array it stores. Then decode it into a String to finally parse it with Jackson. The decoding is done like this:

```
String data = new String(value.toByteArray(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

And this, in fact, returns a String. But that String is for sure not a JSON formatted Tweet, but this monster:

> eyJjcmVhdGVkX2F0IjoiRnJpIE1heSAwMyAxMDozOToyNCArMDAwMCAyMDE5IiwiaWQiOjExMjQyNjIxNzQ1Njg5MjcyMzIsImlkX3N0ciI6IjExMjQyNjIxNzQ1Njg5MjcyMzIiLCJ0ZXh0IjoiUG9tcGVvOiBPbWFyXHUyMDE5cyBWZW5lenVlbGEgY29tbWVudHMgXHUyMDE4ZGlzZ3VzdGluZ1x1MjAxOSBcdTIwMTMgRm94XHUwMGEwTmV3cyBodHRwczpcL1wvdC5jb1wvNDY2UTNZS1pLeiBodHRwczpcL1wvdC5jb1wvNGRKSFpWeVJiMCIsImRpc3BsYXlfdGV4dF9yYW5nZSI6WzAsODFdLCJzb3VyY2UiOiJcdTAwM2NhIGhyZWY9XCJodHRwOlwvXC9wdWJsaWNpemUud3AuY29tXC9cIiByZWw9XCJub2ZvbGxvd1wiXHUwMDNlV29yZFByZXNzLmNvbVx1MDAzY1wvYVx1MDAzZSIsInRydW5jYXRlZCI6ZmFsc2UsImluX3JlcGx5X3RvX3N0YXR1c19pZCI6bnVsbCwiaW5fcmVwbHlfdG9fc3RhdHVzX2lkX3N0ciI6bnVsbCwiaW5fcmVwbHlfdG9fdXNlcl9pZCI6bnVsbCwiaW5....

And so on. I've made some testing in a side project to see if this conversion works and it went fine. Here's the class used for testing:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
import bs.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Caca {

static String tocode = "{\"created_at\":\"Tue Apr 23 09:10:22 +0000 2019\",\"id\":1120615888883994624,\"id_str\":\"1120615888883994624\",\"text\":\"RT @chuckwoolery: Largest OIL and GAS find in Historyin West Texas. Dwarfs Saudi, Iran, and Iraq. Did you hear about this In the MSM? NO.\\u2026\",\"source\":\"\\u003ca href=\\\"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/download\\/iphone\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\"\\u003eTwitter for iPhone\\u003c\\/a\\u003e\",\"truncated\":false,\"in_reply_to_status_id\":null,\"in_reply_to_status_id_str\":null,\"in_reply_to_user_id\":null,\"in_reply_to_user_id_str\":null,\"in_reply_to_screen_name\":null,\"user\":{\"id\":3545646375,\"id_str\":\"3545646375\",\"name\":\"Tom Willoughby\",\"screen_name\":\"willogus\",\"location\":\"USA\",\"url\":null,\"description\":\"MAJ. USA (Ret) \\u201cDUSTOFF\\u201d\\/\\/Retired-Teacher\\/Administrator\\/ Independent Voter\",\"translator_type\":\"none\",\"protected\":false,\"verified\":false,\"followers_count\":414,\"friends_count\":115,\"listed_count\":1,\"favourites_count\":9322,\"statuses_count\":22038,\"created_at\":\"Fri Sep 04 14:48:46 +0000 2015\",\"utc_offset\":null,\"time_zone\":null,\"geo_enabled\":false,\"lang\":\"en\",\"contributors_enabled\":false,\"is_translator\":false,\"profile_background_color\":\"000000\",\"profile_background_image_url\":\"http:\\/\\/abs.twimg.com\\/images\\/themes\\/theme1\\/bg.png\",\"profile_background_image_url_https\":\"https:\\/\\/abs.twimg.com\\/images\\/themes\\/theme1\\/bg.png\",\"profile_background_tile\":false,\"profile_link_color\":\"4A913C\",\"profile_sidebar_border_color\":\"000000\",\"profile_sidebar_fill_color\":\"000000\",\"profile_text_color\":\"000000\",\"profile_use_background_image\":false,\"profile_image_url\":\"http:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/901525176495599621\\/t2G36W62_normal.jpg\",\"profile_image_url_https\":\"https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/901525176495599621\\/t2G36W62_normal.jpg\",\"default_profile\":false,\"default_profile_image\":false,\"following\":null,\"follow_request_sent\":null,\"notifications\":null},\"geo\":null,\"coordinates\":null,\"place\":null,\"contributors\":null,\"retweeted_status\":{\"created_at\":\"Mon Apr 22 13:01:07 +0000 2019\",\"id\":1120311572730191873,\"id_str\":\"1120311572730191873\",\"text\":\"Largest OIL and GAS find in History in West Texas. Dwarfs Saudi, Iran, and Iraq. Did you hear about this In the MSM\\u2026 https:\\/\\/t.co\\/Eptox0vNEx\",\"source\":\"\\u003ca href=\\\"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\"\\u003eTwitter Web Client\\u003c\\/a\\u003e\",\"truncated\":true,\"in_reply_to_status_id\":null,\"in_reply_to_status_id_str\":null,\"in_reply_to_user_id\":null,\"in_reply_to_user_id_str\":null,\"in_reply_to_screen_name\":null,\"user\":{\"id\":462104542,\"id_str\":\"462104542\",\"name\":\"Chuck Woolery\",\"screen_name\":\"chuckwoolery\",\"location\":\"Texas\",\"url\":\"http:\\/\\/bluntforcetruth.com\\/\",\"description\":\"Hollywood Conservative, Love Connection Host, Back in Two and Two, Fisherman, Navy Vet, Political Activist. Host of Blunt Force Truth w\\/ @markyoungtruth\",\"translator_type\":\"none\",\"protected\":false,\"verified\":true,\"followers_count\":543465,\"friends_count\":2856,\"listed_count\":3854,\"favourites_count\":9982,\"statuses_count\":75643,\"created_at\":\"Thu Jan 12 15:30:41 +0000 2012\",\"utc_offset\":null,\"time_zone\":null,\"geo_enabled\":true,\"lang\":\"en\",\"contributors_enabled\":false,\"is_translator\":false,\"profile_background_color\":\"200E82\",\"profile_background_image_url\":\"http:\\/\\/abs.twimg.com\\/images\\/themes\\/theme1\\/bg.png\",\"profile_background_image_url_https\":\"https:\\/\\/abs.twimg.com\\/images\\/themes\\/theme1\\/bg.png\",\"profile_background_tile\":false,\"profile_link_color\":\"0084B4\",\"profile_sidebar_border_color\":\"C0DEED\",\"profile_sidebar_fill_color\":\"DDEEF6\",\"profile_text_color\":\"333333\",\"profile_use_background_image\":true,\"profile_image_url\":\"http:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/1764172727\\/Chuck_Headshot_normal.jpg\",\"profile_image_url_https\":\"https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/1764172727\\/Chuck_Headshot_normal.jpg\",\"profile_banner_url\":\"https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_banners\\/462104542\\/1499952548\",\"default_profile\":false,\"default_profile_image\":false,\"following\":null,\"follow_request_sent\":null,\"notifications\":null},\"geo\":null,\"coordinates\":null,\"place\":null,\"contributors\":null,\"is_quote_status\":false,\"extended_tweet\":{\"full_text\":\"Largest OIL and GAS find in History in West Texas. Dwarfs Saudi, Iran, and Iraq. Did you hear about this In the MSM? NO. Will you? No. If you do it will be the end of the World because it's fossil fuel. Good news for the average American.\",\"display_text_range\":[0,238],\"entities\":{\"hashtags\":[],\"urls\":[],\"user_mentions\":[],\"symbols\":[]}},\"quote_count\":110,\"reply_count\":181,\"retweet_count\":4868,\"favorite_count\":11615,\"entities\":{\"hashtags\":[],\"urls\":[{\"url\":\"https:\\/\\/t.co\\/Eptox0vNEx\",\"expanded_url\":\"https:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/i\\/web\\/status\\/1120311572730191873\",\"display_url\":\"twitter.com\\/i\\/web\\/status\\/1\\u2026\",\"indices\":[117,140]}],\"user_mentions\":[],\"symbols\":[]},\"favorited\":false,\"retweeted\":false,\"filter_level\":\"low\",\"lang\":\"en\"},\"is_quote_status\":false,\"quote_count\":0,\"reply_count\":0,\"retweet_count\":0,\"favorite_count\":0,\"entities\":{\"hashtags\":[],\"urls\":[],\"user_mentions\":[{\"screen_name\":\"chuckwoolery\",\"name\":\"Chuck Woolery\",\"id\":462104542,\"id_str\":\"462104542\",\"indices\":[3,16]}],\"symbols\":[]},\"favorited\":false,\"retweeted\":false,\"filter_level\":\"low\",\"lang\":\"en\",\"timestamp_ms\":\"1556010622603\"}";

    static Tweet tw = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(tocode.getBytes());
        byte[] encoded2 = tocode.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("byte[]encoded is: " + encoded);

        //String decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded2).toString();
        String decoded = new String(encoded2,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("Decoded is: " + decoded);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        try {
            tw = objectMapper.readValue(decoded, Tweet.class);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Caca.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        System.out.println(tw.toString());
    }
}
```

The second part regards the Jackson parsing which works fine as long as the String deserializing goes as expected. And in this side project works.

Any ideas on why is not decoding properly on the main project? It's all on docker containers so there is no way for me to test with the actual Value object locally. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you first encode your tweet as Base64 before saving it to the database? Because that is the monster you are seeing, the base64 encoded tweet. You either have to decode it again from base64 to a string or not convert it to base64 in the first place.

Comment: If you encode a value and save it. The only logical thing to do is to read and decode it, to get the value back

Comment: Hello Yanick, thanks for your answer. I need to encode it because the method createValue() requires me to provide a byte array as argument. My first intention was to save the JSON as a String so I wouldn't need to do all this messy decodification. I have tried the decodification from Base 64 as follows: String data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(value.toByteArray()).toString() which then leads to this error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 0

Comment: Why use Base64 though? You're already converting the string into a byte array using `msg.value().getBytes()`. Now admittedly I'd strongly suggest that you explicitly specify an encoding, ideally UTF-8, but that should be all you need...

Comment: @Lino that is exactly what I'm trying to do here. The only problem I'm trying to solve is the "how"; because I've used like 10 different ways of creating a String from a byte array and none of them worked.

Comment: @JonSkeet just changed the encoding statement to: Value myValue = Value.createValue(Base64.getEncoder().encode(msg.value().getBytes("UTF-8"))); Then I runned the program again. Using the String decodification mentioned above still returns "the monster". Using: String data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(value.toByteArray()).toString(); returns the same exception mentioned in Yanik comment

Comment: But that's still encoding with Base64. Why? Why not just `Value myValue = Value.createValue(msg.value().getBytes("UTF-8"))`? It's really unclear why you're bringing base64 into play at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you, I finally understood you. Now i get the second error that regards Jackson library but the log I create shows translation goes well. If I tell yoy the truth, I began using Base64 at some point when I got tired of testing other ways of encoding. Post your answer and I'll mark it as correct. You solved what I asked. Thank you again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you should be *able* to get base64 encoding to work here, you don't have to. You're currently converting from a string to bytes, then from those bytes to another form of bytes by applying base64 encoding. Assuming you can transport any arbitrary bytes safely, using base64 is just adding a layer of transformation for no reason. Just convert the text to bytes, specifying the encoding to be more robust:

```
Value myValue = Value.createValue(msg.value().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```